# Simplest & Easy Way To Jail Users

Tags: users, jail

I Need Simplest & Easy Way To Jail Users in there home directories

I am looking tools like " jailkit & MySecureShell "

Or

simple configuration to jailing users (with full help or some good web links )

i want to give users (ssh + sftp) . 2 services to jailed users

the jailed user must not see file system directories or any other directory

just remain in his home directory & do what ever is his home directory